# Implicit declaration of function 'pthread_mutex_init' is invalid in C99

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I am trying to lock a method with a mutec from this article [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html)  it states create a member variable of the class as such

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
```

Then initialize it as such

```
 pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
```

Then use it as such

```
void MyLockingFunction()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    // Do work.
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

I am getting the following warning at step 2 when I initialize it.

```
Implicit declaration of function 'pthread_mutex_init' is invalid in C99
```

What does that mean ? Should I ignore it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means you have not included the header file which declares the function, so the compiler doesn't know anything about it at the point that you use it. You're trying to *implicitly* declare it by using it, which is invalid.

If you check the [man page for `pthread_mutex_init()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/pthread_mutex_init.3.html), it tells you that you should use the following line to import the declaration:

```
#include <pthread.h>
```

If you put that near the top of your source file, the warning will go away.